# Как в каждой итерации прибавлять 1 в атрибут?

Tags: php, html

Это естественно выводится в HTML. Вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы в теге

```
   <input type="text" name="1"/>
```

с каждой итерацией цикла foreach просто прибавлялся 1 в атрибуте name

```
  <?foreach($result as $request):?>  
  <tr>
  <td><?=$request['name']?> <?=$request['surname']?></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="1"/><input type="hidden" name="<?=$request['id']?>"/>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <?endforeach?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?foreach($result as $request):?>  
   <tr>
    <td><?=$request['name']?> <?=$request['surname']?></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="<?= $a += 1?>"/><input type="hidden" name="<?=$request['id']?>"/>                        
    </td>
   </tr>
 <?endforeach?>
```

Comment: сорри, что сам на себя ответил, ну может каму-то буит интересно

Comment: @zow Это позволено. Если всё правильно ответил, тебе даже плюсиГ полагается =))

Comment: только перед циклом сделайте `a=0;`

Comment: только $a до цикла объявите, а-то notice словите, минимум

Comment: Ок, хорошо